# Perl, cmd, $ARGV[0], slow

Tags: performance, perl, cmd, argv

[Strawberry Perl v5.16.3, Windows 7 x64, executing via cmd, eg c:\strawberry> perl test.pl 100000]

SYMPTOM: The following code: `foreach (1..$ARGV[0]) { foo($_); }`, executes roughly 20% slower than if I had included this extra line, before it: `my $num = $ARGV[0];`

QUESTION: Can anyone help me understand why?

Notice, in the second case, that after I initialize and set `$num`, I do not then use `$num` in the loop parameters. Were this the case, I could probably be convinced that repeatedly testing against `$ARGV[0]` in a forloop is somehow slower than a variable that I define myself... but this is not the case.

To track time, I use: `use Time::HiRes; my $time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];` at the top of my script, and: `print "\n1: ", Time::HiRes::tv_interval($time);` at the bottom.

Confused!

Thanks,

Michael

**EDIT**

I am including the entire script, with a comment preceding the offending line... Interestingly, it looks like the time discrepancy is at least partially dependent on my redundant initialization of `%h`, as well as `@chain`... This is getting weird.

```
    use Time::HiRes; my $time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];

    #my $max=$ARGV[0];
    my %h = (1=>1,89=>89);
    $h{1}=1;
    $h{89}=89;
    my @chain=();
    my $ans=0;

    sub sum{my $o=0; foreach (@_){$o+=$_}; return $o;}

    foreach (1..$ARGV[0]-1){
        my $x=$_;
        my @chain = ();
        while(!exists($h{$x})){
            push(@chain,$x);
            $x = sum(map {$_**2} split('',$x));
        }
        foreach (@chain){$h{$_}=$h{$x} if !exists($h{$_});}
    }

    print "\n1: ", Time::HiRes::tv_interval($time);
    foreach (1..$ARGV[0]){$ans++ if ($h{$_}==89);}
    print "\n2: ", Time::HiRes::tv_interval($time);
```

Comment: cannot reproduce conclusively. Could you post complete benchmarking code and state perl version/OS?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Post edited to include some info. Still trying to include important code without making my post hideous...

Comment: Your code seems to produce timings in the range of 1E-5 seconds (10 microseconds). This is far to small to provide usable results. Also, your code doesn't make clear what your are timing. When running a [benchmark](https://metacpan.org/module/Benchmark) with enough iterations, no real difference is visible.

Comment: Try an argument of 100,000. With the line uncommented, I'm getting times around 0.83 seconds. Commented, I'm getting 1.20 seconds. That's a 50% increase.

Comment: I added an analysis as an answer. I cannot detect any difference after collecting multiple timings. If you can provide reproducible data using my tool, then I'd be very interested.

Comment: In your tool, I replaced "your-algorithm" with my script name, commented "use warnings;", and removed 'perl ' from the script call to get it to run properly. It seems that mean(@times) always returns 1, and sigma(@times) always returns 0.816496580927726, no matter the argument passed to my script. Observing the output of say "@times"; the times are very clearly different, by consistent margins.

Answer (score 2):

On my system (perl 5.16.3 on GNU/Linux) there is no measurable difference. The standard deviation of the timings is larger than the difference between measurements of different versions.

For each variant of the script, 10 executions were performed. The `$ARGV[0]` was `3.5E5` in all cases (350000).

Without `my $num = $ARGV[0]`:

```
$ perl measure.pl 
2.369921 2.38991 2.380969 4.419895 2.398861 2.420928 2.388721 2.368144 2.387212 2.386347
mean:  2.5910908
sigma: 0.609763793801797
```

With `my $num = $ARGV[0]`:

```
$ perl measure.pl 
4.435764 2.419485 2.403696 2.401771 2.411345 2.466776 4.408127 2.416889 2.389191 2.397409
mean:  2.8150453
sigma: 0.803721101668365
```

The `measure.pl` script:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.016;
use List::Util 'sum';

my @times = map qx/perl your-algorithm.pl 3.5E5/, 1..10;
chomp @times;

say "@times";
say "mean:  ", mean(@times);
say "sigma: ", sigma(@times);


sub mean { sum(@_)/@_ }

sub sigma {
    my $mean = mean(@_);
    my $variance = sum(map { ($_-$mean)**2 } @_) / @_;
    sqrt $variance;
}
```

With `your-algorithm.pl` being reduced so that only one timing is printed:

```
foreach (1..$ARGV[0]){$ans++ if ($h{$_}==89);}
print Time::HiRes::tv_interval($time), "\n";
```

Comment: When I remove the second foreach and the second print, as you have done, I also find that there is no noticeable difference in speed. But this is not useful, as my script does include the second foreach and the second print, which does produce a difference in speed.

Comment: Ok, I updated so that my timings include that loop as well. The 1-sigma-range still overlaps for both versions. Therefore we cannot deduce that the versions have different run times.

Comment: I guess our systems interpret the script differently. I am still getting very different times, consistently. Thanks.

Comment: They were running with very similar times on my system too. I agree with amon that if we can't reproduce your timing issues we can't figure out why once is taking longer to run

Comment: Matt, what are your OS and Perl version? I'm wondering if the strawberry interpreter or Win 7 x64 is the culprit.